# onchange for dynamically added rows

Tags: php, jquery, html

I wish to get the product of two input fields and display it without submitting the form. I have used array and made a provision to add / delete rows and have used an onchange function to get the product. It works fine for the first array, but not for the rest of the array. Please suggest. Below is the code.

```
    <script>
function calc(A,B,SUM) {
  var one = document.getElementById(A).value;
  var two = document.getElementById(B).value; 
  document.getElementById(SUM).value = one * two;
}

function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 70){                // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i <colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;

        }
    }else{
         alert("Maximum rows allowed are 70.");

    }
}

function deleteRow(tableID) {
            try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            if(rowCount > 1){
                    table.deleteRow(rowCount-1);
            }

            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
</script>   



<form name="form" method="post">
<table id="wo_amt_table2" class="form" border=1px;>
<tr>    
    <td><input type="text" name="wo_qty[]" id="wo_qty" style="width: 100%" onChange="calc('wo_qty','wo_rate','wo_amt')"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="small" id="wo_rate"  name="wo_rate[]" style="width: 100%" onChange="calc('wo_qty','wo_rate','wo_amt')"></td>          
    <td><input type="text" class="small" id="wo_amt" name="wo_amt[]" style="width: 100%" required readonly style="border:0px"></td>
</tr>   
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('wo_amt_table2')" />   
    <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onClick="deleteRow('wo_amt_table2')" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: So are you, or are you not using `jquery`? Cause you have shown vanilla JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because your calc function selects by ID (which will only ever retrieve the first occurrence of an element with that ID). In your case, every time any row is changed, it's recalculating the value of the first row. Does that make sense?

I better solution is as follows:

```
function calc(thisRow){
    var one = thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
    var two = thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value;
    thisRow.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].value = one * two;
}
```

and then the row definition should look like this

```
<tr>    
    <td><input type="text" name="wo_qty[]" style="width: 100%" onChange="calc(this.parentElement.parentElement)"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="small" name="wo_rate[]" style="width: 100%" onChange="calc(this.parentElement.parentElement)"></td>          
    <td><input type="text" class="small" name="wo_amt[]" style="width: 100%" required readonly style="border:0px"></td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT:** Created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cef2pg2e/) to illustrate

Comment: Its unclear whether he wants to use jQuery or not so here is an [unobtrusive example using jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/r9L424tj/6/)

Comment: Many thanks @isick. Could you help me add 'grand summation total' of all the 'sub-totals'.

Comment: Many thaks @prodigitalson

Comment: I'd be happy to help, but it's considered good practice to close this question first and then open a new one. But I'll offer you this hint... The only times the grand total will change is when a row is removed or a new row is re-calculated. Which means if you create a function to sum the sub-totals, you can call it inside the `deleteRow` and `calc` functions to automatically reflect changes.

Comment: @isick... cannot figure out. pls help.

Comment: @SatishJagtap I've added the functionality onto my Fiddle. See the updated version here http://jsfiddle.net/cef2pg2e/2/

Comment: @isick. Thanks a lot!